# pytorch subtracting variables with different dimension

Tags: python, reshape, pytorch, subtraction, cross-entropy

```
conf_loss = cross_entropy_loss(conf_preds.view(-1,num_classes),conf_targets.view(-1))
```

The shape of `x` and `y` are

```
X: torch.Size([69856, 40]) ,  Y: torch.Size([69856])
```

respectively.
Author has mentioned the size as `x:[N,D] and y:[N,]`
but `my y size is [N]` I need to calculate the difference but I am getting out of memory . Can anyone help with the dimension? I should get the final shape after taking the difference as `[N,]`. I need to calculate this `print(log_sum_exp - x.gather(1, y.view(-1,1)))`

```
def cross_entropy_loss(x, y):
        '''Cross entropy loss w/o averaging across all samples.
        Args:
          x: (tensor) sized [N,D].
          y: (tensor) sized [N,].
        Return:
          (tensor) cross entroy loss, sized [N,].
        '''
        print("X:",x.shape)
        print("Y:",y.shape)
        xmax = x.data.max()


        log_sum_exp = torch.log(torch.sum(torch.exp(x-xmax), 1)) + xmax
        print(log_sum_exp.shape)   # torch.Size([69856])
        print(x.gather(1,y.view(-1,1)).shape)   #torch.Size([69856, 1])
        #print(log_sum_exp - x.gather(1, y.view(-1,1)))

        #return log_sum_exp - x.gather(1, y.view(-1,1))
```

Comment: why are you not using pytorch's built in `CrossEntropyLoss`?

Comment: That gives me an error .